# How to unit test instance creation?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a `Carpenter` class that does it's work using a `Lathe` and a `Wood` object.

```
class Carpenter
{
    function Work()
    {
        $tool = new Lathe();
        $material = new Wood();
        $tool->Apply($material);
    }
}
```

`Lathe` depends on an interface called `Material`, so I can easily unit test `Lathe` by giving it a fake `Material` in my unit test. `Wood` doesn't depend on anything, so it can also be easily tested.

```
interface Material {
    // Various methods...
}

interface Tool {
    function Apply(Material $m);
}

class Wood implements Material  {
    // Implementations of Material methods
}

class Lathe {
    function Apply(Material $m) {
        // Do processing
    }
}
```

However, `Carpenter` depends on the concrete classes `Lathe` and `Wood` because it has to create instances of them. That means that as it currently stands, I cannot unit test the `Work()` method without inadvertantly bringing `Lathe` and `Wood` under test.

**How should I change my design to unit test `Carpenter`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple of different directions you can take here:

- Use **Constructor Injection** and simply inject the tool and the material instances into the carpenter.
- If injecting instances doesn't work for some reason (perhaps because you need to create new instances for every invocation of the Work method), you can inject **Abstract Factories** instead.
- You can also use the **Factory Method** approach described by ctford, but that requires you to also create test-specific overrides to be able to unit test, and while that's a completely valid thing to do, it's just more work and in many cases the other alternatives are better and more flexible.

Comment: Interesting. But if you inject an Abstract Factory, aren't you just shifting the unit testing problem to the method that creates the Abstract Factory and injects it into the Carpenter? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, because using an Abstract Factory decouples object creation from behavior, which means you can unit test each in isotaion.

Comment: You can unit test the Abstract Factory itself, but the method that creates the Abstract Factory and then feeds it to a Carpenter will have the same issues as in the original question. You'd have to figure out a way to inject a Testing Abstract Factory into that method (and I don't think an Abstract Factory Factory would be the way to go :) ... right?

Comment: An Abstract Factory or any other dependency can (and normally should) be injected through the constructor (Constructor Injection). It will be responsibility of the caller to provide the correct factory.

Answer (score 4):

The key is to seperate object creation from object use in `Carpenter`.

```
class Carpenter
{
    function getTool() {
        return new Lathe();
    }
    function getMaterial() {
        return new Wood();
    }
    function Work()
    {
        $tool = getTool();
        $material = getMaterial();
        $tool->Apply($material);
    }
}
```

That way you can override the `getTool()` and `getMaterial()` methods in a `TestCarpenter` class and inject your own `Material` and `Tool` fakes.

The `getTool()` and `getMaterial()` methods can also be unit tested seperately.

[Michael Feathers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052) would call the `getTool()` and `getMaterial()` methods "seams", because they are points where fakes can be inserted without changing the surrounding code.